# Finding Largest Number in an Array From User Input

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that finds the largest number in array of integers than are inputted by the user using JOptionPane. Here is the code I have s far but I am getting errors when compiling.

```
import javaz.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Week9Largest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int [] x = new int [7] ;
string myString;
int myInt;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
    myString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter " +  "integer " + (i + 1));
    myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
    x[i] = myInt;           
    }
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
        if(myInt[i]>largest){
            largest = myInt[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest number in array is : " +largest);

  }
```

Comment: String myString; - use capital S for String and javax.swing.JOptionPane (not javaz.)

Comment: You're also missing a closing curly bracket `}`

Comment: When posting a question you should state the expected and observed results.  The expected result is obvious here, but you should report what compiler errors you see.

Answer (score 2):

Correct this:

```
 string myString;
```

To:

```
 String myString;
```

Here is your code after correct some issue it's ok:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = new int[7];
    String myString;
    int myInt;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        myString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter " + "integer "
                + (i + 1));
        myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
        x[i] = myInt;
    }
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] > largest) {
            largest = x[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest number in array is : " + largest);

}
```

Because you has mistakes in this loop:

```
   for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(myInt[i]>largest){
        largest = myInt[i];
    }
```

After correction became:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] > largest) {
        largest = x[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### There are Many Errors in Your Code:

1)It is `javax` not `javaz`

```
import javaz.swing.JOptionPane
```

to

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
```

2) It is `String` not `string`

```
string myString;
```

to

```
String myString;
```

3) You are Missing a `closing` curly Brace `}`. Add one `}` at the end of your program.

4) Apart from this, there is `logical` error in your code.

Correct Code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Week9Largest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String myString;
int myInt,numbers[] = new int[7];
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
    myString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Enter " +  "integer " + (i + 1));
    myInt = Integer.parseInt(myString);
    numbers[i] = myInt;           
    }
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
        if(numbers[i] > largest){
            largest = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest number in array is : " +largest);
    }    
}
```

You are using `x` for no reason, Also you are using `numbers.length` while `numbers` is not defined.

Instead Refer the above code, Declare `numbers` or use `x` as an array and copy the user input values into that `variable`, then display the largest value using the
`for` loop.